# Delete records in a data extension using its primary key with AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have a data extension which has around 90 million records and we are trying to keep it updated only for 6 months of data with the date range being a date column inside the D.E, we were doing with SQL query but it was breaking up lot of times, then I came with using AMPScript by creating a D.E with all the primary keys that need to be deleted and then retrieving them using AMPscript and delete them using a self posting landing untill all the required records or deleted. Here is my code for it

```
      %%[

 var @rows, var @row, var @rowcount,var @deleteCount, var 
    @lookupvalue, var @numRowsToReturn
  SET @numRowsToReturn = 0
  SET @rows = 
  LookupOrderedRows("Delete_Test",@numRowsToReturn,"RowDate desc", 
"ProcessedFlag",0)
SET @rowcount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowcount do

var @ProcessedFlag, @RowDate, @RowKey , VAR @timeBefore, @timeAfter, 
@delcount
SET @row = row(@rows, @i)
SET @ProcessedFlag = field(@row , "ProcessedFlag")
SET @RowDate = field(@row , "RowDate")
SET @RowKey = field (@row, "RowKey")
SET @timeBefore = now()
SET @delcount = 
DeleteData(“Clone_TBU_Contact_Hist_180_Days_dev”,”pk_ch_data”, 
 @RowKey)

 SET @timeAfter = now()

]%%

 deletecount: %%=v(@delcount)=%%
 total deleted in batch: %%=v(@count)=%%
 Started: %%=v(@timeBefore)=%%
  Ended: %%=v(@timeAfter)=%%, count: %%=v(@rowcount)=%%

  %%[

 next @i ]%%

 %%[ else ]%%

 No rows found

 %%[ endif ]%%
```

When I test it in a landing page, I can retrieve all the 2000 records but when I add the deletedata function it fails, Can you please suggest me how can I improve my code. Thank you

Comment: RowKey  is primer key field  ?

Comment: Yes, row key is the primary key field in the DE of the keys which contains the keys of the primary key field from the main D.E, processedflag is boolean which determines which records were deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every one, I figured it out in a different way, I programmed it in a way where I would delete the keys in the D.E of keys and target D.E at the same time and use a self submitting page which would autorefresh every 1000 seconds and would do so until no rows are found. Here is my code.

```
    %%[
var @rows, var @row, var @rowcount,var @deleteCount, var @lookupvalue, var 
@numRowsToReturn
SET @numRowsToReturn = 0 /*0 or -1 returns the maximum of 2000*/
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Delete_Test",@numRowsToReturn,"RowDate desc", 
"ProcessedFlag",0) /* Looking Up the rows within the D.E of keys*/
 SET @rowcount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
for @i = 1 to @rowcount do
var @ProcessedFlag, @RowDate, @RowKey , VAR @timeBefore, @timeAfter, 
@deletecount,@lookupValue, @rowsUpdated
SET @row = row(@rows, @i)
SET @ProcessedFlag = field(@row , "ProcessedFlag")   
SET @RowKey = field (@row, "RowKey")
set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("SEND_DT") 
set @lookupValue = @Rowkey 
 set @deleteCount = DeleteData("Clone_TBU_Contact_Hist_180_Days_dev"," 
 pk_ch_data", @lookupValue) /*  Deleting the keys in he target D.E */ 
 set @deleteCount2 = DeleteData("Delete_Test","RowKey", @lookupValue)
 ]%%

<br>Row %%=v(@i)=%%, rank: %%=v(@ProcessedFlag)=%%, firstName: 
 %%=v(@RowDate)=%%, Key: %%=v(@RowKey)=%%
  deleteCount: %%=v(@deleteCount)=%%
 deletedinKeys: %%=v(@deletecount2)=%%, count: %%=v(@rowcount)=%%
 %%[
  next @i ]%%
  %%[ else ]%%
  No rows found
 %%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 6):

You can apply [row-based data retention](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_april_2019_cab_data_retention.htm&type=5) to the Data Extension. You can configure it for 6 months. This would take care of it for you without any coding necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the data retention policy only deletes the records which were created in the last 6 months, however our criteria is we use a custom date column inside the data extension that determines which records have to be deleted and this process takes place everyday as new data is loaded in as an automation, Thank you